# How to get Uber Python/Flask example to work

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a web app using the Uber api (https://developer.uber.com/v1/tutorials/).
In their tutorial they link to an example application on github with instructions to get it running. (https://github.com/uber/Python-Sample-Application). When I try running the sample application I get HTTP 400 errors. An example of the output that I get on the console is shown below.

```
(venv)192:Python-Sample-Application jason$ python app.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:7000/
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014 05:37:28] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type     ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xab\x01\x00\x00\xa7\x03\x03T')
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014 05:37:28] "??T   ??p},֤,??IknL?]????????C@?J??$?#?" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014 05:37:28] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type     ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\x9b\x01\x00\x00\x97\x03\x01T')
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014 05:37:28] "??T   ???=?-???????"u?Pg,??t?sBa`?J??$?#?" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014 05:37:28] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x00\x00E\x01\x00\x00A\x03\x00T')
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014 05:37:28] "EAT   ??^??????<)?W?e-???\?U~?0:=?=</5" 400 -
```

I've pasted the instructions from the github project below.

> How To Use This
>
> 1. Navigate over to https://developer.uber.com/, and sign up for an Uber developer account.
> 2. Register a new Uber application and make your Redirect URI `http://localhost:7000/submit`  ensure that both the profile and history OAuth scopes are checked.
> 3. Fill in the relevant information in the config.json file in the root folder and add your client id and secret as the environment
>      variables UBER_CLIENT_ID and UBER_CLIENT_SECRET.
> 4. Run export UBER_CLIENT_ID="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"&&export UBER_CLIENT_SECRET="YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
> 5. Run pip install -r requirements.txt to install dependencies
> 6. Run python app.py
> 7. Navigate to `http://localhost:7000` in your browser

On the Uber developer page I've checked all boxes for my app and set the redirect. In my `config.json`, I've added lines for the `UBER_CLIENT_ID` and `UBER_CLIENT_SECRET` fields. I've run the export command from step 4 and echoed both environment variables to confirm that the variables are set. I created a virtualenv to install the dependencies and then ran the pip install and python app.py instructions. I'm running OS x and have tried with both Chrome and Safari and both browsers say they fail to make a secure connection to localhost.

Comment: The entries in your log make it  look as if a *non-HTTP* client tried to connect. Try running on a different port on your local machine, perhaps some software is trying to connect to 7000 speaking a binary protocol? You can alter the last line of `app.py` to change the port number.

Comment: In any case, the lines are *otherwise harmless*; are you able to connect with your browser at all? If the lines bother you, move the app to a  different port number, such as 8000 or 8080.

Comment: I just tried changing the port number to 8000 and 8080 and I'm still getting a bad http request output

Comment: **Something** is connecting with those ports and sending your Flask server binary data. Whatever that may be, it is not talking the HTTP protocol, which is why you see those errors. This has nothing to do with Flask or Python otherwise.